# How can I change Chrome's title bar text?

Tags: 12.04, unity, themes, titlebar

I have chromium web browser open and I don't want it to say Chromium Web Browser in the title bar in unity. It can be blank for any app I have open as well using 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a neat program called `wmctrl` that allows controlling window properties, including titles.

For instance, run this in terminal:

`while [ 1 ]; do wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -T " "  ; done`

This will set whatever your active window is to the text you specify with -T flag. Thus, any active window, once you bring it up, will get set to blank title. So all you have to do is bring up the application, and there you have it !

You can put that into a script, and make that script a startup application. For more info on how to achieve that, read [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/295286)

Note, `wmctrl` isn't default package. you have to install it with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`

Answer (score 1):

The title bar in chrome (or any browser) is typically set by the webpage. Your going to have a very hard time overriding that.

If you switch to gnome 3 there are ways to fool the system into displaying an empty title bar. There is no way to do this in unity that I am aware of, and no way to do it application specific without removing window decorations. If your willing to remove window decorations then you can try Maximus for gnome 3 or develspie. There are other programs and scripts that will let you modify window proprieties. The one your looking for is "undecorate".

You could of course compile your own window manager and just change the parts that display the window title. However that's pretty advanced.  If your just trying to stop prying eyes you could write a quick chromium extension that sets a title to "".